# Why occurs json parse error of manifest with Opera extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, opera-extension

There is extension with *manifest v3*. It works in developer mode on Opera and Chrome. But when I try to upload it to [addons.opera.com](https://addons.opera.com), occurs error:

> manifest.json is invalid. Please correct it and try uploading again.
> The parser reported: {'resources': ['/script/domain/player.js'],
> 'matches': ['https://music.yandex.ru/*'], 'extension_ids': []} is not
> of type 'string'

You can see that in message uses `'`, but in file all of it is `"`

```json
{"resources": ["/script/domain/player.js"],
"matches": ["https://music.yandex.ru/*"],
"extension_ids": []}
```

Whats problem?

Comment: Apparently, they don't support MV3 extensions.

Comment: Furthermore Opera validates and shows your extension in its stable channel only after MANY months.
Some people say that Opera's review system has been stopped for almost 2 years.
The good thing is that your extension will be visible and downloadable from Opera store by "Opera Next" or "Opera Developer" browser user practically immediately after the submission phase